# Gatsby-Source-Facebook-Graphql Plugin

Tags: graphql, gatsby

I cannot find the data in graphql with this plugin, all I can get is the FB id.

This is my gatsby-config

```
{
      resolve: `gatsby-source-facebook-graphql`,
      options: {
        // Facebook account or page ID
        pageId: XXXXXX,
        params: {
          fields: [
            'address',
            'birthday',
            'hometown',
          ],
        },
        // Access Token from facebook
        accessToken: 'XXXXXX',
      },
    },
```

I know I've got the access token right because w/o it facebook disappears from the graphiql panel.

Thanks in advance.[image]

Comment: Do any of these fields return anything and do you see any errors/warnings in the terminal when you run `gatsby build`? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user

Comment: Nah, that's the issue, I see no returned data. No errors on build either.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, I needed to add the correct permissions to FB API.

[image]